# When puppet-master controls puppet-client, can it be configured without a certificate?

Tags: puppet

In general, when we use puppet-master to control the puppet-clients.

```
puppet agent --server puppet-master-hostname -test

​​puppet cert -s CLIENT-HOSTNAME  # or -a for all
```

But I have a question,
for convenient, when puppet-master controls puppet-client, can it be configured without a certificate?

Comment: The Puppet CA component of the server requires this for connection authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to sign each client's cert once, but the clients each need a cert, and the master has one too.  Although this does allow the data exchanged between agent and master to be encrypted to protect it from snooping, the most important function is to allow agent and master each to authenticate the other.  That helps prevent the agent from accepting configuration from an impostor master, and to prevent the master from delivering sensitive configuration details to an impostor client.

There are options for configuring the master to automatically sign client certs, but no option for doing without certs altogether.